# Actionscript 2 converted to Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have this flash program that I downloaded and extracted the code from here and to load it onto a online presentation site, I need to convert it into Actionscript 3.

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
//Frame 161 
//---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
stop();    

//---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
//Symbol 44 Button 
//---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
on (release) { gotoandstop (1); }  

//---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
//Frame 101 //---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
stop(); gotoandplay (31);    

//---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
//Frame 30 
//---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
stop();    

//---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
//Frame 1 
//---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
stop();    

//---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
//Symbol 32 Button 
//---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
on (release) { gotoandplay (102); }  

//---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
//Symbol 16 Button 
//---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
on (release) { play(); }
```

Here is the working copy: http://static.howstuffworks.com/flash/fuel-cell-animation.swf
I don't think it's too complicated so how will I easily do this? Are there converters?
Thanks.

Comment: This site is not intended as a place where you post a problem and then get someone else to do the work for you. You should try to do the work yourself, and if you encounter concrete coding problems, then ask about them. Make sure to include what you tried, what you expected to happen and what actually happened.

Comment: I have never coded ActionScript before! I was just asking for advice on if it's possible and maybe ways to do it. Sorry

Comment: I didn't really know where to put it. I'm a bit new to stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this [Migrating AS2 -> AS3 Article](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/first_as3_application.html) and this [AS2 to AS3 migration table](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-archive/actionscript/as3_migration_table.html).

These should answer most of your doubts.

For example:

```
on (release) { gotoandplay (102); }
```

Could be replaced with:

```
function mouseUpHandler( event:MouseEvent ):void
{
   this.gotoAndPlay(102);
}
this.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler );
```